# XUnit CollectionFixture instantiating multiple times

Tags: c#, xunit.net

I'm just getting started with [`ClassFixtures`](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context#class-fixture) and collections in [xUnit](https://xunit.net/) so its possible I'm doing this wrong, but my understanding is that I can create a `ICollectionFixture<MyFixture>`, assign it to a collection via the `CollectionDefinitionAttribtue` and then all the test classes that have the `Collection` attribute with the same connection name will share the same instance of the fixture.

First a simple case to prove that a `Fixture` is only instantiating once per test class

```cs
public class SampleFixture:IDisposable
{
    public static int ConstructorCount { get; set; }
    public static int DisposeCount { get; set; }

    public SampleFixture()
    {
        ConstructorCount++;
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        DisposeCount++;
    }
}

public class SampleTestClass1 : IClassFixture<SampleFixture>
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper outputHelper;
    private readonly SampleFixture sampleFixture;

    public SampleTestClass1(ITestOutputHelper outputHelper, SampleFixture sampleFixture)
    {
        this.outputHelper = outputHelper;
        this.sampleFixture = sampleFixture;
    }
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        this.outputHelper.WriteLine($"Test1 - Constructor Count: {SampleFixture.ConstructorCount} DisposeCount: {SampleFixture.DisposeCount}");
        Assert.Equal(1,SampleFixture.ConstructorCount);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        this.outputHelper.WriteLine($"Test2 - Constructor Count: {SampleFixture.ConstructorCount} DisposeCount: {SampleFixture.DisposeCount}");
        Assert.Equal(1,SampleFixture.ConstructorCount);
        
    }
}
```

Run the tests, and they both pass. 1 pass through the constructor means both tests in the test class are using the same instance of my fixture.  Cool beans.

Now let's create a `CollectionFixture`, add another test class and decorate both with the same `Collection` attribute.

```cs
[CollectionDefinition("SampleFixture")]
public class SampleFixtureCollection : ICollectionFixture<SampleFixture>
{
    
}
public class SampleFixture:IDisposable
{
    public static int ConstructorCount { get; set; }
    public static int DisposeCount { get; set; }

    public SampleFixture()
    {
        ConstructorCount++;
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        DisposeCount++;
    }
}

[Collection("SampleFixture")]
public class SampleTestClass1 : IClassFixture<SampleFixture>
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper outputHelper;
    private readonly SampleFixture sampleFixture;

    public SampleTestClass1(ITestOutputHelper outputHelper, SampleFixture sampleFixture)
    {
        this.outputHelper = outputHelper;
        this.sampleFixture = sampleFixture;
    }
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        this.outputHelper.WriteLine($"Test1 - Constructor Count: {SampleFixture.ConstructorCount} DisposeCount: {SampleFixture.DisposeCount}");
        Assert.Equal(1,SampleFixture.ConstructorCount);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        this.outputHelper.WriteLine($"Test2 - Constructor Count: {SampleFixture.ConstructorCount} DisposeCount: {SampleFixture.DisposeCount}");
        Assert.Equal(1,SampleFixture.ConstructorCount);
        
    }
}

[Collection("SampleFixture")]
public class SampleTestClass2 : IClassFixture<SampleFixture>
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper outputHelper;
    private readonly SampleFixture sampleFixture;

    public SampleTestClass2(ITestOutputHelper outputHelper, SampleFixture sampleFixture)
    {
        this.outputHelper = outputHelper;
        this.sampleFixture = sampleFixture;
    }
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        this.outputHelper.WriteLine($"Test1 - Constructor Count: {SampleFixture.ConstructorCount} DisposeCount: {SampleFixture.DisposeCount}");
        Assert.Equal(1,SampleFixture.ConstructorCount);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        this.outputHelper.WriteLine($"Test2 - Constructor Count: {SampleFixture.ConstructorCount} DisposeCount: {SampleFixture.DisposeCount}");
        Assert.Equal(1,SampleFixture.ConstructorCount);
        
    }
}
```

Now all my tests fail.  Check out this message from the failed test in the 2nd test class:

> Test1 - Constructor Count: 3 DisposeCount: 1

It appears the constructor is called **3 times!**  Once during the fixture collection startup, and then once more for each test class.

What gives here?  Both my tests are tied to the same collection, but each test class is getting its own instance of the test fixture.

Have I done something wrong here or is this a bug? (I found no mention of it in GitHub).

Using xUnit v2.4.1  with .net core 2.1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out.

When using Fixture collections, the test classes should not implement the IClassFixture interface.

Changing

```cs
[Collection("SampleFixture")]
public class SampleTestClass1  : IClassFixture<SampleFixture>
{...}
```

to

```cs
[Collection("SampleFixture")]
public class SampleTestClass1  // <-- Removed IClassFixture<SampleFixture>
{...}
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem without any coding issue, but cleaning and rebuilding solved the issue.